# Difference between (split, align) and (gather, aligned)?

Tags: numbering, amsmath

Here is an MWE which shows that they seem to do the same thing. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other for typesetting groups of equations? I would prefer the `align` syntax because it allows `intertext`. In the other case, the alignment is limited to `aligned` environments within the larger `gather` environment. Any thoughts are welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

%==================
% gather+aligned
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}


%==================
% align+split
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I gather (pun intended) that you're considering these two setups because they let you assign a single equation number to each equation pair. Note that the setup of both groups, as stated in the MWE, is currently `overkill` because you could actually replace all `gather` and `align` instances with `equation` and get the exact same outcome. To really get a chance to distinguish between the pros and cons of the two setups, you need to make their structures a bit richer. (Currently, there's really not enough there to distinguish between them.) Please consider editing your MWE accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the 2nd example would work just fine without `split`, and as @Mico says, the 1st one can use simple `equation` instead of `gather`.

Comment: @tohecz Without `split` both lines would be numbered.

Comment: @AdorableCreature "recent changes" (To the AMS alignments??)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: recent changes refer to my comment in egreg's answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the example alignment the following are equivalent; actually, the correct outer environment to use is `equation`, as the following code will show; using `split` or `aligned` for the inner environment in this case doesn't matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum,geometry}
\geometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% equation+aligned
\begin{equation}\tag{EA}
\begin{aligned}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% equation+split
\begin{equation}\tag{ES}
\begin{split}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% gather+aligned
\begin{gather}\tag{GA}
\begin{aligned}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% gather+split
\begin{gather}\tag{GS}
\begin{split}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{split}
\end{gather}
\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% align+split
\begin{align}\tag{AS}
\begin{split}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{split}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
%==================
% align+aligned
\begin{align}\tag{AA}
\begin{aligned}
x &= a + b\\
y &= c+ d
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

In the output it's possible to see that the correct spacing is obtained with `equation`. Use `align` or `gather` only when there is *really* more than one equation to number.

One should also note that "equation+split" results in a different vertical spacing than "equation+aligned" (which isn't really expected).

[image]

Comment: So far, this is my definite guide concerning spacing around displayed math. Why is this stuff not explained somewhere? I checked `amsldoc.pdf`, `Mathmode.pdf`, and `mathtools.pdf` (`\SwapAboveDisplaySkip`), but no explanation anywhere...

Comment: `aligned` needs the easy-to-forget prefix `\!`.

Comment: What happens if one wants to tag / label multiple lines? The natural approach would be to use `align`, but then the spacing is inconsistent with equation...

Answer (score 5):

`split` can still work with narrow spaces while `aligned` cannot!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.5+0.1}{4}{%
\endgraf\noindent\pnode(.5\linewidth,0){T}
%
\begin{equation*}\!
\begin{aligned}
\framebox[\n\linewidth]{aligned \n}
\end{aligned}\tag*{Def}
\end{equation*}
%
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\framebox[\n\linewidth]{split \n}
\end{split}\tag*{Def}
\end{equation*}
%
\endgraf\noindent\pnode(.5\linewidth,0){B}
\psset{linecolor=blue}
\ncline{T}{B}
\pcline[nodesep=-\dimexpr\n\linewidth/2](B)(B)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are we supposed to see here?

Comment: @mafp: It should be obvious.

Comment: No, I don't see it. You say `aligned` does not work, but the picture looks OK to me.

Comment: @mafp: With `aligned` the wider box is not properly aligned.

Comment: This might very well be a feature, to have sufficient space between content and tag.

Comment: I see it, but I don't understand it.  What is it in the code that's causing the left-right shift in the last example?  The entire example includes a very large number of unfamiliar expressions, making it difficult to understand by non-experts (and maybe some experts as well).  "Unfamiliar": I admit that lots of cool LaTeX tricks are unfamiliar to me, but I do know enough to know that there's a lot here that would be unfamiliar to most users.