# What's the difference between split and aligned?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I don't understand the difference between the `split` and `aligned` environments introduced by amsmath, so I'm posting this question as a place to collect what subtle details there may be. One thing observable straight off is that `split` only works with two columns, whereas `aligned` works with an arbitrary number of columns. But they are similar in other immediately visible ways:

- Both have to be wrapped in another math-introducing environment, like `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`
- Both permit only a single `\tag{...}` for the entire group, not one tag for each line *(EDIT: not sure where I got that impression, in fact neither permits *any* `\tag`, though `aligned`'s friend `gathered` does permit a single `\tag`, as described here)*

I searched existing questions on this site about what differences there may be between these environments. I did find this question: [Difference between (split, align) and (gather, aligned)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63929), where---despite the title and phrasing of the question---most of the answers focus just on the difference between the `split` and `aligned` environments themselves.

*EDIT: Collecting the differences noted so far.*

- As one answer to [the above question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63929) points out, inside `equation` environments (but not inside `gather` or `align` environments), the `split` and `aligned` environments have different vertical spacing from the surrounding text.
- As another answer to that question points out, when the body of these environments gets very long, their horizontal placement starts to diverge.
- As Mico noted in comments, section 3.7 of the `amsmath` User Guide notes that `aligned` (together with `alignedat` and `gathered`) accepts an optional `[t]` or `[b]` argument, for explicit vertical placement of any equation tags. `split` does not accept any such argument.
- As egreg notes in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187938/whats-the-difference-between-split-and-aligned#187958), `split` will on the other hand honor the `tbtags` or (default) `centertags` option to the `amsmath` package. Whereas `aligned` and its friends will not.
- As Mico's comments also suggested, but I did not immediately appreciate, `split` is not supposed to go together with any other typeset material on the same display line. On the other hand, `aligned` and its friends can be freely combined with other unaligned materials, or even other blocks of `aligned` and so on. They will be horizontally juxtaposed and vertically centered. I've explained this further in [an answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187938/whats-the-difference-between-split-and-aligned#188233).

Perhaps that exhausts the differences between `split` and `aligned`: though if others know of other differences, please point them out.

Comment: Did you check out section 3.7, "Alignment building blocks", of the user guide of the `amsmath` package? It mentions two important differences -- in addition to the ones you mention in your write-up -- between the `split` environment on the one hand and the `aligned` environment (and its close relatives, the `gathered` and `alignedat` environments) on the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I was reading through that guide currently. (Searching on it turned up too many results.) That section doesn't explicitly mention `split`. Of the two features cited there, the first (permitting additional unaligned text on the same row) doesn't distinguish `aligned` and friends (`gathered`, `alignedat`) from `split`, at least that's what my testing shows. The other feature cited there *is* different between them: `aligned` and friends take an optional `[t]` or `[b]` argument, but `split` does not.

Comment: Since `split` is generally used inside environments such as `equation` and `equation*`, what's said in the first two sentences of the first paragraph of section 3.7 of the user guide (i) does apply to `split` (even though `split` isn't mentioned "explicitly"...) and (ii) helps set up distinguish what's different about `aligned` (and `gathered` and `alignedat`).

Comment: But `aligned` also has to be used inside `equation` or the like; there is no difference there with respect to `split`. And if you try it, you'll see that you can add further unaligned text on the same `equation` line, after either of them. That is: `begin{equation}\begin{XXX}...\end{XXX}\text{ hello}\end{equation}` gives the same results whether `XXX` is `aligned` or `split`. (And in neither case can the `begin{equation}` or something similar be omitted.)

Comment: In your last comment you use something outside the inner environment (`\text`); In that case I tend to use `aligned`. I *only* use `split` inside `equation`s, when I want to split them; but not only a part (because that would be “aligning”), I use split when the whole equation must be divided, hence the construction is always (in my case) `\begin{equation}\begin{split} … \end{split}\end{equation}` (or `equation*`).

Comment: One of the differences is that `split` obeys to the `tbtags` or `centertags` option.

Comment: Further reading and testing shows that I was wrong in my earlier comments replying to @Mico. `split` will *sometimes work* with additional text on the same display row, but it's not designed to do so and sometimes it won't work. I've added an answer giving more details.

Answer (score 21):

One important difference is that `split` obeys to the `centertags` (default) or `tbtags` option. Here is an example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[
%  tbtags,
%  leqno,
]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
\begin{split}
c&=d+{}\\
 &=e+{}\\
 &=f
\end{split}\\
g&=h
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the same with uncommented `tbtags`:

[image]

Now also `leqno` is uncommented:

[image]

To the contrary, `aligned` will have the equation number according to the vertical alignment option: centered for `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}`, at the top for `\begin{aligned}[t]...\end{aligned}`, at the bottom for `\begin{aligned}[b]...\end{aligned}`. Thus it's better to use `split` whenever possible, if equation numbers are involved. (I rarely use equation numbers, so I usually don't bother.)

Comment: Finally I understood how splits work in the align environment!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another difference I notice. According to the AMS User Guide (p. 6 and p. 29 in the Version 2.0 copy I have):

> The `split` structure should constitute the entire body of the enclosing struc- ture, apart from commands like `\label` that produce no visible material.
>
> The `split` environment is designed to serve as the entire body of an
>   equation, or an entire line of an `align` or `gather` environment.
>   There cannot be any printed material before or after it within the
>   same enclosing structure:
>
> ```
> \begin{equation}
> \left\{ % <-- Not allowed
> \begin{split}
> ...
> \end{split}
> \right. % <-- Not allowed
> \end{equation}
> ```

However, in my testing (conducted before reading these passages), this constraint seems nowadays often not to be enforced. Here's an example that *doesn't* work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y=0
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\left. \begin{aligned}
B'&=-\partial\times E,\\
E'&=\partial\times B - 4\pi j,
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
x=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
% \begin{split}
% y=0
% \end{split}
% \qquad
\left. \begin{split}
B'&=-\partial\times E,\\
E'&=\partial\times B - 4\pi j,
\end{split}
\right\}
\qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\enspace
\begin{split}
x=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: LaTeX output]

and in the log we see a related error message:

> Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `` `split' `` here;
>   (amsmath)                trying to recover with `` `aligned' `` on input line 31.

However, if the comments are removed from the previous source, then it typesets fine (and there is no Warning in the log):

[image: LaTex output]

The horizontal spacing is just a bit different from that of `aligned`. I wish I understood better why multiple `split`s on the same display line works in the second case but not the first. Still, it is clear that the docs say this is not its intended use, and as the first example shows, it can't be expected to perform that use reliably. If you want an aligned block of equations on a line together with additional material (including but not only including other aligned blocks), you're supposed to use `aligned` and friends (`alignedat`, `gathered`).

Comment: Another difference is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192069/19356.

Answer (score 0):

I was referred here from a search engine. I assume this might still be actively viewed question and might be worth pointing out another difference I found between `aligned` and `split`.

I can't confirm this in documentation but `split` seems to respect binary alignment in a particular column from the surrounding environment `align`. This may be useful if one wants to give a separate tag to a inner group of expressions. I couldn't get it worked this with `aligned`.

For instance, in this example, there are two groups of some inner expressions (top and bottom), which received a separate tag and can still respects a mutual alignment in a particular column. It seems very easy to achieve with `split`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    a                  &= b \\
    cc                 &= dd
  \end{split} \\[2ex]
  \begin{split}
    z_{1}              &= a + b + c + d \\
    z_{\mathrm{LONGT}} &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \\
    z_{234}            &= a + b + c + d \\
    z_{56}             &= a + b + c + d 
  \end{split} \\[2ex]
  a                    &= b & c &= d & e &= f \\[2ex]
                       &    & \begin{split}
                                z_{1}             &= a + b + c + d \\
                                z_{\mathrm{LONG}} &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \\
                                z_{234}           &= a + b + c + d \\
                                z_{56}            &= a + b + c + d 
                              \end{split} \\[3ex]
                       &    & g &= h &   &
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]