# Why can't split with curly-brace be inside align but it can be inside gather?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

The following code snippet will guide you through the issue chronologically.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\section*{gather+aligned}
\begin{gather}
    \left\{\!
    \begin{aligned}
        x &= \cos t\\
        y &= \sin t
    \end{aligned}\right.\\
    x^2 +y^2 =1
\end{gather}


\section*{gather+split}
\begin{gather}
    \left\{
    \begin{split}
        x &= \cos t\\
        y &= \sin t
    \end{split}\right.\\
    x^2 +y^2 =1
\end{gather}


\section*{align+aligned}
\begin{align}
    &\left\{\!
    \begin{aligned}
        x &= \cos t\\
        y &= \sin t
    \end{aligned}\right.\\
    &x^2 +y^2 =1
\end{align}


\section*{align+split}
It cannot be compiled.
%\begin{align}
    %&\left\{
    %\begin{split}
        %x &= \cos t\\
        %y &= \sin t
    %\end{split}\right.\\
    %&x^2 +y^2 =1
%\end{align}

\section*{align+split+nobrace}
It can be compiled.
\begin{align}
    &
    \begin{split}
        x &= \cos t\\
        y &= \sin t
    \end{split}\\
    &x^2 +y^2 =1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why can't `split` with curly-brace `\left\{` and `\right.` be inside `align` but it can be inside `gather`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `amsmath` user guide:

> The `split` environment is designed to serve as the entire body of an equation, or an entire line of an `align` or `gather` environment. There cannot be any printed material before or after it within the same enclosing structure.

In particular, you can't have `\left\{` to the left and `\right.` to the right of the `split` material.

For more on this subject, see the posting [What's the difference between split and aligned?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187938/5001)

Comment: You said that "In particular, you can't have `\left\{` to the left and `\right.` to the right of the `split` material." but apparently it works inside `gather` as shown in my code given above.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch - Well, under some circumstances -- such as in the `gather` example you've given -- one *can* indeed get `split` to work. However, it might not work in other circumstances. So either the user guide is a bit too strident, or it's actually trying to give helpful advice by steering you away from trouble without covering every single possible contingency and circumstance. The upshot, though, *is* correct: Don't use `split` inside `gather` and `align` environments. Use `aligned` instead, unless you want to run into problems from time to time...

Comment: or use it for what it is meant to, aka not for `cases` constructions

Comment: So `split` is only recommended for `equation`?

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch - No. You can use `split` whenever its material will be the only material on a given line.