# Incompatibility between split and empheq?

Tags: amsmath, split, empheq

I have an issue using `split` inside an `empheq` environment.

When combining both environments, the alignment of the `empheq` is broken.

Any clues ?

If this is a duplicate or an obvious/known incompatibility, my apologies in advance.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}


\begin{document}

Equations that can fit
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

Equations that can't
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

So I split the first equation
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& \begin{split}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{split}\\
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
a\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in the first two you have the (strange) setting with only a right hand side so all the terms are after a `&` but in the third equation there is no `&` before bbbbb so it comes to the left of the aaaa as the split is after a `&`

Comment: You'll get the same with `algin` instead of `empheq`, it is caused by the missing `&` as @DavidCarlisle mentioned. And you'll have to remove the `&` prior to `split`.

Comment: That's precisely the difference between the split and the aligned syntax.

Comment: @Bernard, now I just found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187938/whats-the-difference-between-split-and-aligned and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192069/why-cant-split-with-curly-brace-be-inside-align-but-it-can-be-inside-gather. I guess i will remove my post...

Comment: @BambOo: I don't think it's necessary, as it's sometimes hard to question the (answered) question which match *exactly* yours. I'd rather add a link to these questions as a complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also compatible with `aligned`, which can replace `split`. Note that `empheq` loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`, so you only have to load the first of these packages.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

Equations that can fit
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

Equations that can't
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

It works with `aligned`:

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& \begin{aligned}[b]
  & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
  & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{aligned}\\
 & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed it is working with `aligned`. +1 for the answer, however it doesn't really solve the issue between `split` and `empheq`. Thank you anyway

Comment: I very rarely use `split`, so I didn't even try to understand what was happening there, as most of the time, `aligned` (or `alignedat`) can replace it

Answer (score 1):

Adding the missing `&` and removing the one prior to `split` does solve your issue:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}


\begin{document}

Equations that can fit
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

Equations that can't
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{empheq}

So I split the first equation
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
 \begin{split}
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{split}\\
&bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
a\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]