# Tagging multi line equations

Tags: equations, align, labels

Often I have a chain of equations but later on I only want to refer that the first statement is equal to the last one. There are some options to do that:

```
\begin{align}
  \label{equation}
      a    
  &=  b \\ 
  &=  c \\
  &=  d \\
  &=  e \\
  &=  f
\end{align}
Equation~\eqref{equation} gives $a=f$.

\begin{align}
      a    \label{equation_first}
  &=  b \\ 
  &=  c \\
  &=  d \\
  &=  e \\
  &=  f    \label{equation_last}
\end{align}
Equation~\eqref{equation_first}--\eqref{equation_last} gives $a=f$.

\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{align*}
      a    
  &=  b \\ 
  &=  c \\
  &=  d \\
  &=  e \\
  &=  f    \numberthis \label{equation2}
\end{align*}
Equation~\eqref{equation2} gives $a=f$.

\begin{equation}
  \label{equation_split}
  \begin{split}
        a    
    &=  b \\ 
    &=  c \\
    &=  d \\
    &=  e \\
    &=  f 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
Equation~\eqref{equation_split} gives $a=f$.
```

[image: My four options]

- The first one is just bad, as (2)--(5) are displayed, but not included in the reference.
- The second one is more or less okay, but after all it is *one* equation while it looks like I need six equations.
- The third one is a hack I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end) (alternativly I could have used `align*` and lots of `nonumber`s). This version is okay, but does not look that good. Sure, I could put the tag on the center line, but that‘s manual work (I have to (not forget to) redo that stuff after adding some lines) and there is not always a center line.
- The fourth option looks quite good. However, I pretty much always used `align[*]` up to now. Are there any problems with `equation+split`?

How do you tag multi line equations? Why?

Comment: There are no problems with `equation+split` and this is absolutely the right way do go here. Split is just an aligning environment which automatically sets the single label to where you want it: to the centre.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Ah, perfect. I will use that option then. :)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- although "center tags" is the default for `split`, it's also possible to specify that the tag is to go at the bottom (for tags on the right) or the top (for tags on the left) with the option `tbtags`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, did not know that. I added some links for comparison between `split` and `aligned` below.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    a &= b\\
      &= c\\
      &= d\\
      &= e\\
      &= f
      \label{eq:EqAligned}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{eq:EqAligned}...
\end{document}
```

It centers the number vertically even if the number of equations is even, and the reference works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please explain the difference (and advantages/disadvantages) to my fourth option, thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert of Latex, and I've never used the split environment, but aligned worked always fine so far. I've found this question, if you're interested: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187938/whats-the-difference-between-split-and-aligned

Comment: @Keba http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187938 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63929. In your case, `split` results in more vertical space above and below the math part. And the centering is handled a bit different. Hardly visible here, but you may want to check for bigger math lines.

Comment: @MarcoG [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for answering here and for participating in this community.