# How to create a horizontal list that is centered?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, multicol, tasks

I'm trying to recreate the below image where the defining of the variables is kind of like a horizontal list but without labels. I have tried using `tasks` and `multicols` but can't quite figure this out.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

Consider the following intervals:
\begin{multicols}{2}
A = (1,5] \\
C = [4,7) 
\columnbreak
B = [1,4) \\
D = (2,5) 
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Comment: Please post compilable code rather than fragments. It's maths: use `amsmath` with the environments it provides for alignment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is maths, use one of the environments provided by `amsmath` for such things. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Consider the following intervals:
\[
\begin{aligned}
  A &= (1,5] & B &= [1,4) \\
  C &= [4,7) & D &= (2,5) \\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned things]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is precisely what `align` does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Consider the following intervals:
\begin{align*}
A &= (1,5]&
B &= [1,4) \\
C &= [4,7) &
D &= (2,5) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you just beat me. I shouldn't have spent time typing in the second line! I'll delete my (nearly identical) post.

Comment: What is the difference between using `\begin{aligned}` vs. using `begin{align*}`? I notice the answer from @cfr puts it inside a math-mode environment but this one does not.

Comment: @dylanjm Your question has an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63929/difference-between-split-align-and-gather-aligned). If one is ever to number the equation, arguably the output is nicer with `align` and `subequations`.

Answer (score 1):

You also can have full control on the spacing between the columns with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Consider the following intervals:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A &= (1,5]&\hspace{6pc}
B &= [1,4) \\
C &= [4,7) &
D &= (2,5)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]